# Index-Match and #REF

Tags: excel-formula

I'm using this line of code:

`=INDEX('Inventory Prices'!$D$2:$K$802, MATCH(C88,'Inventory Prices'!$C$2:$C$818,0), MATCH($D87,'Inventory Prices'!$D$1:$K$1))`

Column A has a drop down for item category, Column B brings up a drop down list using INDIRECT(A-) and Column C brings up the item code for the item in B from our database.  The code then looks to a price sheet, finds the item and displays one of 6 prices (based upon discount, selected via another drop down in Column D.

The inventory is 817 lines long.  The code has worked for 38 items but suddenly the last 15 out of the 817, each of the 15 brings back #REF.  The data is all Number.  I have removed any formatting.  There doesn't seem to be an explanation for why suddenly and on the last 15 items, the code doesn't work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: your match range has more rows than your Index.  Change to `=INDEX('Inventory Prices'!$D$2:$K$818, MATCH(C88,'Inventory Prices'!$C$2:$C$818,0), MATCH($D87,'Inventory Prices'!$D$1:$K$1))`

Comment: Yup, it sure does...:hangs head in shame:.  Thank you so much!